# How do I show a standard card on Alexa Echo show using Lambda?

Tags: javascript, amazon-web-services, aws-lambda, alexa-skills-kit

I'm a student so I'm quite new to this :p 
I have created a code to create a conversation between a client and Alexa. However I want to show pictures during a conversation.

E.g

User says "I want to a map from the zoo." .
Alexa confirms it by saying "Do you want a map from the zoo?".
User says "yes".
Alexa then shows a map of the zoo.

My problem is that I am unable to make the standard card to show the image of the zoo. I am using Amazon S3 to make the image address and I have already made it public.

Is there a code or any way to allow my code to show the standard card with the map on it? I am using Lambda to make my code.

Any help would be appreciated!

Answer (score 0):

You can utilize Alexa Body Templates to display images as well.

These templates have designs to include you place images in various styles.

Templates Reference:
https://developer.amazon.com/docs/custom-skills/display-template-reference.html

After logging into developer.aamazon.com, you can view the below link which has more references
https://developer.amazon.com/alexa/console/ask/displays

Hope this helps !!